# how can I dynamically pull version from git into capsule.bxb?

Tags: git, bixby, bixbystudio

I don't want to rely on remembering to update the version number in `capsule.bxb` manually each time I update the app.

In python, I normally do this:

```py
    def get_latest_git_tag(path):
        repo = git.Repo(path)
        tags = sorted(repo.tags, key=lambda t: t.commit.committed_datetime)
        latest_git_tag = tags[-1]
        return latest_git_tag
```

I want `capsule.bxb` to read a dynamic version variable from git.

In bash,

```
    git describe --abbrev=0 | cut -c 2-8
```

I see that there is a ShellJS that would let me run this command, but I don't think it could execute in `capsule.bxb`, could it?

I want to be able to do something like

```
    capsule {
      id (altbrains.quotations)
      version (<getsversion>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently this functionality is not available. However, I would recommend that you file a feature request [here](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests) to allow your fellow developers to upvote this functionality and to provide the product team with valuable insight.